# single process on php

Tags: php, cron

I need to generate some charts and reports, but only when my DB is modified. Because the time needed to generate the reports varies between 2 and 4 seconds and the number of reports varies too I'm thinking to use a cron which checks for DB modifications. The thing is that I don't wish to start  generating another report, while other is running. In other words I don't wish to start another process while the previous one is still running. How can I accomplish this?

my cron look like this:

```
*/1 * * * * php /home/john/public_html/reportsGeneratorByCron.php
```

Comment: You can put some flag on database or in some file on disc which you will have to check with other processes to find out if it's unlocked.

Comment: I would investigate using database triggers to add a report request to a queue and then have a process which reads report requests from the queue and process them.  This does not sound like something for a cron job.

Comment: take a look at this kind of approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357187/php-how-do-i-implement-queue-processing-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/) which works like CRON but allows you to specify the time between one process ending and another one starting, rather than the time between starts like CRON.

Take a look at the website - there's plenty of documentation, examples and use cases:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
*/1 * * * * pgrep reportsGeneratorByCron > /dev/null || php /home/john/public_html/reportsGeneratorByCron.php
```